# How do I disable DVD player auto start when a DVD is inserted by using Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line

If anyone can help me with this it would be the best! I have just installed 150 Mac minis in a hotel and I'm using remote desktop management to control them. Now I need to disable DVD player auto start when a DVD is inserted. I would like to know if it's possible to do this by using Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just copy the preference files? I don't know anything about managing multiple Macs, but there's probably some better way to do this.

Opening DVD Player can be disabled with

```
defaults com.apple.digihub com.apple.digihub.dvd.video.appeared -dict action 1
```

To reenable, use

```
defaults com.apple.digihub com.apple.digihub.dvd.video.appeared -dict action 105
```

The preference for the desktop picture is in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist`, but I don't know how to change that directly.

You can find where the preferences are stored by diffing the output of `defaults read` before and after changing a preference.

Comment: `command not found` on Catalina.  Is there an update for this answer?

Comment: @james.garriss The command name was missing from the commands :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ARD for this sort of thing, but can't you set system preferences en masse for a group of Macs? If so, the preference you're looking for is in the CDs & DVDs preference pane.